# jQuery add attributes to div

Tags: jquery

I do not believe that any of the questions I have searched on here answers this for me.

I am trying to set a attribute on a div when a link is clicked. I can't get it to set the attr() for the div no matter what I do. I believe that attr() is the right way to go and looking for some help if not moving forward in the right direction.

I am doing fairly straight forward use case:

```
<a href="#">Click here to set</a>
<div id="subs">This will have title added to the div</div>

$(function() {
  $('a').on('click', function() {
   $('#subs').attr('title','Test Title');
  });
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pertrai1/L55Rc/

Comment: how did you check whether its working or not. use google chroms developer tools or firebug in firefox to see the title changed

Comment: are you loading jquery before this script?

Comment: Yes you are right it does seem to be working. I was replying on Firebug lite inside of jsfiddle and was not getting the return I was expecting. I then turned to dev tools and did see that attr() was indeed working.

Comment: I am wondering what the reason would be that negative numbers are next to questions and answers and when they are, why a person does not add a reason why they put a negative number?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$( function() {
  $('a').on('click', function() {
  $('#subs').prop('title', function() {
       return "I am a title";
  });
  });
});​
```

use prop() instead if attr() is not working!

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KBk9L/)

Comment: Yes it did very much so. Thank you